# How many number of subdomains can a domain have?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I am planning to build a service based on subdomain like wordpress or tumblr.
I want to know what is the maximum number of subdomains a domain can have.

Answer (score 5):

Well. The absolute theoretical maximum is 2^504, but that assumes no limitations on the octets making up the names. If you want the names limited to ASCII letters and digits, the answer is 111444219848545291112918149658401217019177846881717006276548100629318214534968256903948922840416256 (that is, 36^63).

In another sense the answer is "Far, *far* more than you will ever need".

Answer (score 2):

This would be more dependant on the DNS server than on the standard. BIND allows for a maximum of 16'777'216 objects per zone file while Microsoft DNS is reported to be stable up to 20'000 objects per zone. This does not mean however that you will be able to max out the DNS object limits as your average website owner is going to want to have a meaningful object name for their sites sub domain, additionally the maximum character count for fully qualified domain names is 255 characters with no individual segment (between dots) being longer than 63 characters as per the DNS specifications.

Effectively what this means is that while there are restrictions and limitations the practical answer is that you are unlikely to encounter limitations due to DNS specifications in any reasonable timeframe.